# bluebird.js P and Promise globals not available

Tags: javascript, dojo, promise, bluebird

I have included bluebird.js script as written here:
https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#quick-start

So now I'm expecting this:

> The global variables Promise and P (alias for Promise) become
>   available after the above script tag.

But, inspecting global Promise variable, I find that is the native Chrome implementation, not the bluebird promise. Well, that seems logical not to override native implementation. But still, there isn't event the global P variable from bluebird. Why is that?

Another option I tried is to use:

```
var prom = require("bluebird");
```

but when I try to require, it shows "Error: undefinedModule". One possible reason is that I'm using dojo, which has its own module loader with define/require functions. So it could be some kind of name clash.

**After all this, the main question remains - how can I use bluebird promises, when globals (Promise and P) are not there, and require is not working?**

Comment: Did you put the bluebird.js file on your own server?   Are you 100% sure that your `<script>` tag URL is correctly pointing to your copy of bluebird.js?  It sounds like your script tag is not properly loading the library.

Comment: Yes, I'm loading it from local folder. In dev tools, I can see that script is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluebird assumes your modules are node like and thus uses the module loader instead. You can trick it into thinking there are no modules involved.

Here is a hack around this limitation:

First - Keep a back up of the `require` function and delete it:

```
var oldRequire = require;
require = null
```

Then, include bluebird.

Finally, restore it.

```
var require = oldRequire
```

So the total course of action would look like:

```
 <script>
     var oldReq = require;
     require = undefined;
 </script>
 <script src="bluebird.js"> </script>
 <script>
      require = oldReq;
      oldReq = undefined;
 </script>
```

Comment: One small (but important) addition - I need to do the same with 'define' function, otherwise its not working. Having done that, this solution seems to work. Do I understand correctly, that bluebird adds methods to native Promise object? Doesn't that introduce some compatability issues later on?

Comment: @andree no, it does not add properties to the native promise object it creates its own promise object - there are no compatibility issues :)

Comment: horrible and genius

Answer (score 0):

Bluebird does notice that you're using an AMD module loader (from [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/loader/amd.html#loader-amd), in your case) and does register itself as a module without defining any globals.

For some odd reason, it does however declare a `"Promise"` module not a `"Bluebird"` one. Using `require("Promise")` should work.

Comment: It throws "Error: undefinedModule"